# Обрезать строку перед последним символом

Tags: php

Есть строка: `Главная>Новости>Новость 1`.

Необходимо обрезать строку перед последним символом `>`, чтобы осталось только `Новость 1`.

Как это сделать с помощью *php*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Вы бы сами без труда справились с этой задачей, если бы разложили ее на составляющие (это называется декомпозицией):

1. Найти положение последнего искомого символа
2. Отрезать строку после него

   ```
   $pos = strrpos($str, '>');
   if (!$pos !== false) {
       $str = substr($str, $pos + 1);
   }
   ```

или

1. Разбить строку на массив по искомому символу
2. Найти длину массива
3. Получить последнйи (длина - 1) элемент массива

   ```
   $bits = explode('>', $str);
   $str = $bits[sizeof($bits) - 1];
   ```

Бонусом - волшебный однострочник

```
return explode('>', $str)[substr_count('>', $str) - 1];
```

Comment: `array_pop(explode('>', $str))` короче.

Comment: @Visman, ага, я вывалился немного из отрасли